# ExpandoObject not accepted for routeValues in Action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to be able to choose which properties is added to my object before using it in my action method helper. So I used an ExpandoObject to achieve this.

```
dynamic routeValues = new ExpandoObject();

if (...) { routeValues.FirstParam = "one"; }
if (...) { routeValues.SecondParam = "two"; }

helper.Action("MyAction", "MyController", routeValues);
```

It compiled successfully but at runtimes the routeValues object seems to be ignored.

**Any solution on dynamically choosing properties of an object ?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need any dynamics or ExpandoObjects, a simple [RouteValueDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx) will do the job:

```
var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();

if (...) { routeValues["FirstParam"] = "one"; }
if (...) { routeValues["SecondParam"] = "two"; }

helper.Action("MyAction", "MyController", routeValues);
```